# Getting "A corrupt or unuseable certificate was received" exception from jsp

Tags: java, http, jsp, ssl, weblogic

I'm calling one web service from unix batch file and successfully made request and got the response too.

But when I call the same web service from the jsp page, then I'm getting BAD_CERTIFICATE error.

```
FATAL Alert:BAD_CERTIFICATE - A corrupt or unuseable certificate was received.
javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: FATAL Alert:BAD_CERTIFICATE - A corrupt or unuseable certificate was received.
    at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.fireException(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.fireAlertSent(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.handshake.HandshakeHandler.fireAlert(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.handshake.HandshakeHandler.handleHandshakeMessages(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.MessageInterpreter.interpretContent(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.MessageInterpreter.decryptMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.processRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.readUntilHandshakeComplete(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.completeHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.WriteHandler.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.io.OutputSSLIOStreamWrapper.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:123)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:150)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:364)
    at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpsURLConnection.java:37)
    at jsp_servlet._test._util.__testservice._jspService(__testservice.java:590)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:226)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:124)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:394)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:309)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3392)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2140)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2046)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1366)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:200)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:172)
```

Need help on this.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the Weblogic Server version? What type of certificate is configured in server?

Comment: Weblogic server version is 10.0 and I don't know about the type of certificate configured.

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution for this is to enable JSSE but you are on very old WLS version. Anyways, as per Oracle KM:

Set the following JAVA_OPTIONS depending on your case and restart servers.

Post WLS 10.3.3

```
-Dweblogic.ssl.JSSEEnabled=true
-Dweblogic.wsee.client.ssl.usejdk=true
-Dweblogic.wsee.skip.async.response=true
-Dweblogic.wsee.client.ssl.stricthostchecking=false
-Dweblogic.webservice.client.ssl.adapterclass=weblogic.webservice.client.JSSEAdapter
```

Pre WLS 10.3.2

```
-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol
-Dssl.SocketFactory.provider=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
-DUseSunHttpHandler=true
-Dweblogic.wsee.client.ssl.usejdk=true
-Dweblogic.wsee.skip.async.response=true
-Dweblogic.wsee.client.ssl.stricthostchecking=false
-Dweblogic.webservice.client.ssl.adapterclass=weblogic.webservice.client.JSSEAdapter
```

Reference:FATAL Alert:BAD_CERTIFICATE - When handshaking with an external WebService with certificates unsupported by Certicom (Doc ID 1671346.1)